# What is the correct Expression in SSRS?

Tags: c#, ssrs-2012

I have this expression

```
=Fields!Value.Value
```

The report output in one column is :

**Header Information:**

- Date: 01/01/2020~10/06/2020
- Correspondent group/Correspondent: Correspondent
- A/P Dept: ALL
- Output data: Present data

What I want to get is only one data and this is the `Date:01/01/2020~10/06/2020`

How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, you just want to retrieve a single value from a dataset.

I have made a few assumptions.

1. Your dataset is called `DataSet1`
2. The row you want always starts with "`Date:`"

The following `LOOKUP()` will work.

```
=LOOKUP("Date:", Left(Fields!Value.Value,5), Fields!Value.Value, "DataSet1")
```

**Note:** The dataset name must match your dataset name exactly, it is case-sensitive and must be enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
=Mid(Fields!Value.Value,InStr(Fields!Value.Value, "Date"),InStr(Fields!Value.Value, "2020" )- 5)
```

Or this is the much better solution than the one above:

```
=Mid(Fields!Value.Value, InStr(Fields!Value.Value, "Date"), InStr(Fields!Value.Value, "Correspondent")-(instr(Fields!Value.Value,"Date")+1))
```

Comment: I forgot, the report output of =Fields!Value.Value is only 1 column but  has 30 rows if I will group them but if not the result is Header Information only which is in the top row, I want to get the Date:01/01/2020~10/06/2020 only.

Comment: Use First() will take the fist row. or do I understand something wrong